# for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop, linear-programming

Hi I have the following code which I believe have indexed wrongly and so Im not getting the answer I am looking for

```
Diesel_matrix = xlsread('test_diesel.xlsx','Sheet2');

Diesel_supply = Diesel_matrix(:,1); % Power output of diesel generator

hourly_cost = Diesel_matrix(:,2);  % Diesel cost of running genreator at that output




 for z = 1:21

 A    = [-PV_supply -WT_supply -Diesel_supply(z)*ones(24,1)];

   f = [CRF_PV*CC_PV; CRF_WT*CC_WT; (CRF_Diesel_generator*CC_Diesel)+sum(hourly_cost(1:z))]  ;


 b = -Demand;

 [x,fval,exitflag] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
 end
```

I am trying to loop only for the third column of matrix A.
I would like to loop for all the rows in "Diesel_supply" per row of matrix A

at the moment, the code works for 21 sets of x outputs but column 3 is either row 1,2,3 etc up to row 21 of "Diesel_supply". Wheras I am trying to get it for row 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 etc up to row 21 of "Diesel_supply".
This will allow me to examine all the elements in "Diesel_Supply"

Comment: @user643469 -- I am assuming PV_and WT_supply are constant matricies? What dimensions are they? It sounds like the code works till element 22 and then falls apart. Is it possible that element 22 presents input that causes an error?

Comment: The problem is that I need each row of A to account for the 21 values in "Diesel_supply" column individually. however I don't know how to code/index the for loop and "A" because the size of row 1 and 2 are both 1 element whereas row 3 (which takes its values from the "Diesel_matrix" is any possible value between row 1 and 21 of "Diesel_matrix" so I am trying to account for each value individually

Comment: at the same time I also need to do this in such a way that I can access and output the optimum x value (size(x) = 3) and also be able to know which is the "z" value for each of the 24 rows that produces these optimum ponts

Comment: PV_supply and WT_supply are both size 24x1

Comment: what is causing all this problem is that I know the values in PV_supply and WT_supply but I don't know the values in Diesel_supply - all I know is that they can be any of 21 different numbers and will be different (probably) for each of the 24 rows

Comment: Humm. It looks like each iteration of the loop is independent of the other loops so it would be easy to initially ignore the for loop, make sure it works on one of the 21 sub problems, and then add the for loop later on.

Comment: thanks but that makes no sense to me at all ( I am a matlab beginner btw) - am I right in saying that the A matrix cannot exist if not in some sort of similar form -                                            A = [-PV_supply -WT_supply -Diesel_supply(z)*ones(24,1)] as first of all the diesel_supply(z) is 21 possible elements so in any case there is a size mismatch unless some sort of 3 dimensional format is conducted?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. From what I can gather from your code, each iteration of the for loop will use a matrix 'A' that is going to be a 3x24 matrix. f is going to be a 1x3 matrix. Am I following you correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13763/discussion-between-chessofnerd-and-user643469)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the conversation @user643469 and I had in chat (see link in comments section) and looking at the documentation for linprog afterwards, I think you need to store the results of each z-iteration in a data structure and then pick the best one after the loop has finished.

As I understand, the generator has 21 different modes you can run it in and it is subject to 24 different constraints. Each mode changes the constaints a little.

Instead of

```
[x,fval,exitflag] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
```

use

```
val = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
results(z) = val;
```

After the loop has finished, you will be left with a results matrix with the dimensions 4x21 where the first column contains x-values, second contains fval values and third contains exitflag values. You can then you through this 'results' matrix to determine which of the 21 modes you have available to run the generator in.